# Захват видео с экрана

Tags: c++, видео, кроссплатформенность

Задался таким вопросом, какую библиотеку лучше использовать, для захвата видео с экрана, чтобы была возможность реализовать захват при помощи видеокарты? Кодек соответственно `h264` буду использовать, так же хотелось, чтобы была поддержка кроссплатформенности, так как хочу поставить себе второй `OC Linux` и пользоваться своей программой там.

Comment: opencv возможно вместе с ffmpeg. Но лучше opencv ничего нет.

Comment: @jNX спасибо, буду разбираться. В прочим, можно и в ответ кидать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Opencv](https://opencv.org/) возможно вместе с [ffmpeg](https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/index.html). Но лучше opencv ничего нет. Открытая библиотека с множеством примеров. Единственное слабо оптимизировано и приходится паралелить ручками что бы быстро работало. Могу выслать на почту неплохую книгу по opencv.

Comment: Буду только рад почитать. romasolomahin@gmail.com

Comment: @jNX Буду только рад почитать. naidv88@gmail.com